# Im trying to figure out how to find a power series representation for 2xarctan(4x) but cannot figure out.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a power series representation of the function $$f(x)=2x \arctan(4x)$$ but cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried finding through the derivative/antiderivative method but was not successful with it. can someone give me a hint please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the series for $\arctan$ by itself?

Comment: Take the power series of Gregory/Madhava.  Multiply argument  by four times and power series coefficient by $2 x$ times.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\rm{arctan}x=\int\dfrac 1{1+x^2}\rm dx=\int(\sum (-x^2)^n)\rm dx=\sum\int(-1)^nx^{2n}\rm dx=\sum(-1)^nx^{2n+1}/{(2n+1)}$$